# Git - Does master commits align by commit time/date?

Tags: git

Iv'e done the following flow due to an issue that we've encountered:

I have 2 local repository clones -> rep_A, rep_B (both are on master)

1. rep_A : commit #1
2. rep_B : commit #3
3. rep_A : commit #2
4. rep_B : commit #4
5. rep_A : push to master
6. rep_B : git pull
7. rep_B : push to master

(all commits were done consecutive in time, 1 was the first 4 was the last)

I expected the master to look as such:

- commit 4
- commit 3
- commit 2
- commit 1

though the master showed the following:

- commit 4
- commit 2
- commit 3
- commit 1

can someone please help explain this behavior?

Comment: the example i did was clone the repositories to 2 different folders on my local machine.. not 2 branches on a local clone..

Comment: Ah...OK you should have mentioned this.  But why would that make a difference.  If one repo is behind the remote `master`, you would still need to pull before pushing.

Comment: no branches, both folders.repositories were on the master branch..

Comment: yep i pulled before i pushed in rep_B (i added it now to the description)

Comment: Did you actually check the SHA-1 hashes of all commits?  I doubt they are the same as the four original commits.

Comment: why would they change? and why would the order will be dependent on the hashes?

Comment: Are you asking why a new merge commit would not match any of the previous four commits?  You should update your question and show _all_ SHA-1 hashes for everything.  This should clear things up.

Comment: is there a chance it happened because i didn't rebased before the push?

Comment: Run `git log --oneline --graph`. The history could be not linear. As for the commit ordering, https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log.html#_commit_ordering

Comment: `--graph` implies the `--topo-order`. I would instead recommend specify `--pretty=fuller` and check both author and committed times

Answer (score 1):

When `git log` has *two* commits it *could* display "simultaneously", it must choose one to show first.  That is, the fundamental problems here are: *What are the actual time stamps?* and *How does your viewer linearize non-linear history?*

As a slightly different (and probably more obvious) example, suppose you run:

```
git log br1 br2
```

where `br1` and `br2` are two different branch names with two different tip commits.  Which commit should Git show first?  In general, Git's answer (for `git log` and `git rev-list`) is: *use the one with the latest committer date*.  There are flags to change this: `--author-date-order`, `--date-order`, and `--topo-order` (`--graph` implies `--topo-order` as [max630 noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539271/git-does-master-commits-align-by-commit-time-date#comment76078420_44539271)).

The *committer date* is separate from the *author date*.  Every commit has *two* time stamps, one for when the commit was originally written, and a second for when it was actually committed.  These two are often the same, but you can get them split up in various ways, including by rebasing (the copied commit gets a new committer date while keeping the original author date) or by emailing patches with `git format-patch` and applying them with `git am`.

Other things—other viewers than `git log`—have their own strategies for dealing with this problem, of which commit(s) to show first when there is a choice.  (There is also the potential issue, when dealing with multiple computers on which people make commits, that the wall-clock-time clock on each computer can be wildly wrong.  Fortunately you took that out of the equation by using just one computer, which presumably doesn't randomly reset its date to last week and then next year and then back to today.  Even if your computer's clock is wrong, it's probably *reasonably consistently* wrong.)

Now, with the above in mind, let's take a look at the commits you made and the resulting commit *graph*.  We start with three identical Git repositories: the one on some central server (perhaps GitHub), and two clones rep_A and rep_B.

We'll put newer (by commit date) commits towards the right, along with their linkage (remember, each commit "remembers" its parent).

```
server: ...--F--G   <-- master

rep_A:  ...--F--G   <-- master

rep_B:  ...--F--G   <-- master
```

Now you added your four commits, but in alternating repositories:

```
rep_A:  ...--F--G--1-----3   <-- master

rep_B:  ...--F--G-----2-----4   <-- master
```

(Note that the server has none of these yet.)  Next, you did a `git push` from rep_A to the server, so now the server has the `F--G--1--3` sequence, then you ran `git pull` on rep_B.

The `git pull` command means: *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.*  We may need to know what the second command was, because it could be `git merge`, or it could be `git rebase` ... and `git rebase` *changes the committer date*.

Here's what you have after the `git fetch` step:

```
server: F--G--1-----3   <-- master

rep_B:  F--G-----2-----4   <-- master
            \
             `1-----3   <-- origin/master
```

Now we need to know if you configured `git pull` to run `git rebase` (or, equivalently, ran `git pull --rebase`).  If you *did*, here is what you get in rep_B:

```
rep_B:  F--G--2--4   <-- origin/master
                  \
                   1'--3'   <-- master
```

But these would be displayed in the normal (i.e., reverse) order as `3'` (that's the copy rebase made of the original `3`), then `1'`, then `4`, then `2`.  So probably that's *not* the case.  If you added a merge instead, this is what you get in rep_B:

```
rep_B:  F--G-----2-----4--M   <-- master
            \            /
             `1-----3---’  <-- origin/master
```

In any case, you then push from rep_B back to the server (and perhaps fetch and merge-or-rebase, i.e., `git pull`, back into `rep_A` as well).

If you now go to display these commits using `git log master` or equivalent, Git will start with the merge commit `M`, because it has just one commit to show right now: that's the merge commit itself.  But `M` has *two* parents, so next, Git puts both `4` and `3` into the list of commits-to-show.

What happens now depends on what order you told `git log` to use.  By default, it will pick the commit with the highest date to show.  That would be commit `4`; it would show that and put its parent, commit `2`, into the list.  Then it would pick the commit in the list with the highest date, which would be commit `3`.  It would show that, and put `3`'s parent `1` into the list.  Then it would pick the commit with the highest date, which would be `2`, and so on.

On the other hand, if you gave it the `--topo-order` flag, it would pick one of the two parents of the merge as before, choosing `4`.  Then it would make sure that it shows *all of the parents of `4` back to the point of the fork at `G`* before showing commit `3`, so you would see `4`, then `2`, then `3`, then `1`, then `G`, then `F`, and so on.

Based on the output you observed, it would seem that whatever viewer you are using is doing this last sequence.  But there are a number of assumptions I have made here (merge vs rebase for instance).